# solving integral in rectangular method in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is my code to make an integration in the rectangular method in the matlab

```
f=@(x) (x^(1/2))
a = 1  
b = 10 

% step size
h = 0.25 

n = 0 % the counter

xn= a + (n * h)
%%
%Rectangle Method:
s=0
for i =0:n-1
s = s + f(xn)
end
Rectangle = h * s
```

the answer should be around 20, but i'm getting 29.5
what's the problem?

Comment: Your variable `xn` is not updated, since it is outside of the loop

Comment: `x^(1/2)` is the same (in this case) as `sqrt(x)`. Use the latter, it's less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

1) xn is not updated.

2) number of points `n` is set to zero.

There are other minor issues which I did not fix, e.g. right and left boundary points should both contribute to the sum with weight 1/2.

Quick fix:

```
f=@(x) (x^(1/2));
a = 1;  
b = 10 ;

% step size
h = 0.25; 

n = (b-a)/h; % the counter


%%
%Rectangle Method:
s=0;
for i =0:n-1
    xn= a + (i * h);
    s = s + f(xn);
end
Rectangle = h * s;
```